# How to use Transfer Matrix Method to calculate reflection amplitude for a Gires-Tournois etalon?

Tags: matrix

The problem asks to show that r=-(r1-exp(-i \delta))/(1-r1*exp(-i\delta)), where r1 is the reflection amplitude for the vacuum-air interface, and delta= 4\pi n l/\lambda cos(\theta). The device is composed of a glass plate with parallel interfaces, of which one is coated with metal, acting as a perfect reflector. A plane wave hits the uncoated interface first at an angle theta. The problem has been solved in conventional methods, but I have yet to find a solution using TMM. If anyone has insight, it would be greatly appreciated.